# PowerShell Module won't import from $profile

Tags: powershell, module, profile

In the very last line of my profile, I have `Import-Module PSReadline`.

And yet the module doesn't load when I launch PowerShell. I have to import it manually. I have another module (pscx) set to import in my profile, and it loads perfectly. Why not PSReadline?

Comment: Which profile file are you editing (name and path)?  Also are you using the PowerShell console or PowerShell_ISE?

Comment: I use the console 95% of the time.          $profile = "C:\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Comment: Is there anything before that in your profile script that may be failing?  Try moving the Import-Module psreadline to the very top of the profile script.

Comment: thanks, that led me in the right direction. A function was silently failing, preventing other parts of the profile to selectively fail. Once the function was fixed, everything else fell into line.

Comment: I converted that comment to answer if you'd like to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything before that in your profile script that may be failing? Try moving the Import-Module PSReadline to the very top of the profile script.